# Using persistence to display number of times visits for a BB Application? 

Tags: blackberry, persistence

I have developed an application. I want to display a message before the user starts implementing my application. Like when it is used first time i want to show "Count = 1". And when app is visited second time, "Count  = 2".

How can i achieve it? I had done such thing in android using `sharedperferences`. But how can i do it in blackberry. I had tried something with `PersistentStore`. But cant achieve that,  for i dont know anything about the Persistance in BB.

Also i would wish to restrict the use for 100. Is it possible?

sample codes for this will be appreciable, since i am new to this environment..

Comment: Use persistent store and get value from this and increment that value by one and after increase it save that value to the persistent store.

Comment: I had tried somthing like that. but didnt succeed. Can u demonstarte it?

Comment: So would you put that code here..
& which problem you faces.....

Comment: that problem is got solved my friend. I had gone through rupak guided me. And now i got the solution. I had tried to answer to my own question to put the code. But as i have no permssion, i will have to wait 8 hours. Anyway thank u for ur help.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with Persistent Storage.

[Check this nice tutorial about storing persistent data](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Storing-Persistent-Data/ta-p/442785).

Also you can use SQLite. Link to a development guide which describes how to use SQLite databases in Java® applications: [Storing data in SQLite databases](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_data_in_SQLite_databases_1219769_11.jsp).

You can restrict user for trying your application at most 100 times using your own logic with the help of persistent data. But I think there may be some convention, so try Google for that.

Comment: i dont want to include the SQLite for that. I am going for the first.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got it...

I created a new class which implements `Persistable`. In that class i had created an integer variable and set an getter and setter function for that integer...

```
import net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable;


public class Persist implements Persistable
{
    private int first;

    public int getCount()
    {
        return first;
    }

    public void setCount()
    {
        this.first += 1;
    }
}
```

Then in the class which initializes my screen, i had declared persistence variables and 3 functions to use my Persist.java, initStore(), savePersist(), and getPersist()

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
     /*
     * Declaring my variables...
     */
    private static PersistentObject store;
    public Persist p;  

public MyScreen()
{
//my application codes

//here uses persistence
initStore();
        p = getPersist();
        if(p.getCount()<100)
        {
            savePersist();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Dialog.alert(p.getCount.toString());
                        }
        });
        }
                else
                {
                     close();
                     System.exit(0);
                }
}

//three function....
public static void initStore()
    {
        store = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0x4612d496ef1ecce8L);
    }

    public void savePersist()
    {
        synchronized (store) 
        {
            p.setCount();
            store.setContents(p);
            store.commit();
        }
    }

    public Persist getPersist()
    {
        Persist p = new Persist();
        synchronized(store)
        {
            p = (Persist)store.getContents();
            if(p==null)
            {
                p = new Persist();
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

I hope u all will get it right now....
If there are another simple way, plz let me know...
Thanks